# win7 dual boot with ubuntu, bad pool loader BSOD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed ubuntu 19.10 about 1 week ago as dual-boot on my laptop with windows7.

Today I need to use windows7 to do some specific work, though when I start windows I have the start animation starting, then a BSOD saying "bad pool loader".
Does this error sound familiar to some of you?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed on Ram stick and the issue got solved. Not sure from where the problem comes but it seems windows is having issue handling the two ram sticks now.